# "I'm free at around 7PM"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

> I'm free at around 7PM.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using the present indicative instead of future tense when nailing down an action to a time or speaking of things in the future as if they have already occurred. There is even a literary device known as [prolepsis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proleptic), which deals with exactly this.

How often have you heard someone in a movie or TV show say:

> Reach for that gun and you're a dead
>   man.

That is one example of prolepsis. Your example is another.

Answer (score 13):

There’s an argument that “at around” is not strictly correct, as either you’re free **at** 7 p.m. or **around** 7 p.m., but not both.

But it’s certainly widely used colloquially.

Comment: good to know, thx.

Comment: Ther's another argument that 'free around seven' would mean from (say) ten to seven to ten past, while 'free at around seven' means from circa 7 o'clock onwards.  But in reality it all depends on context.

Answer (score 3):

In everyday usage, I say "I'll be free around seven."

Answer (score 1):

It's understandable, and would probably be used by most native speakers too.

It would be more (temporally) correct if you said "I will be free at around 7PM", but I'm not sure that anyone would really pick up on the difference.